# Characters print more than twice (Common Lisp)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to print out a character based on a conditional statement.

```
(defvar enctext)

   (defun encrypt(enctext) 
     (if (eq 'A (first enctext))
      (princ 'H)))
```

And here is what I have for executing the function

```
(load "lisptest.lisp")
;; Loading file lisptest.lisp ...
** - Continuable Error
DEFUN/DEFMACRO(ENCRYPT): #<PACKAGE POSIX> is locked
If you continue (by typing 'continue'): Ignore the lock and proceed
The following restarts are also available:
SKIP           :R1      skip (DEFUN ENCRYPT # ...)
RETRY          :R2      retry (DEFUN ENCRYPT # ...)
STOP           :R3      stop loading file         /home/students/cante008/cs351/lisptest.lisp
ABORT          :R4      Abort main loop
Break 1 [2]> continue
WARNING: DEFUN/DEFMACRO: redefining function ENCRYPT in
     /home/students/cante008/cs351/lisptest.lisp, was defined in C
 ;; Loaded file lisptest.lisp
T
[3]> (setf x '(A))
(A)
[4]> (encrypt x)
H
H
```

At the very end the character 'H' prints twice and i'm not sure why that is.

This is my first step to doing a Caesar Cipher

Answer (score 2):

> [..] a character [..]

When you write things like `'A` or `'H` you're not dealing with characters but **symbols**. Characters are written like this: `#\A` or `#\Space`. To compare characters for equality, use [`char=`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_chareq.htm#charEQ).

> [..] prints twice [..]

Most functions in Lisp return (at least) one value. When you call a function on the REPL (read-evaluate-print-loop), then - as the "P" in "REPL" suggests - the return value(s) of calling that function is printed. The return value of your function is either `NIL` (when the `if` is not taken) or whatever `princ` returns. Looking at [the HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_pr.htm#princ) tells us:

> `princ object &optional output-stream` => `object`

This is to be read as `princ` takes one required parameter (some object to print) and an optional parameter (the stream to print to) and **returns** an object, which is (though I couldn't find it written explicitly) the same object that was passed to it.

Thus, the first `H` is from the `princ`, the second one from the REPL that automatically prints the return value.

As a final remark: Your usage of `defvar` probably shows a misunderstanding of variables in Common Lisp: `defvar` declares the (rough equivalent) to what you might know as "global" variables from other languages. You don't need it for function arguments or passing parameters.

Comment: Nitpicking: you could return zero value with `(values)`, even though it makes little difference.

Comment: @coredump Thanks. I almost *knew* that I was wrong when writing this, but couldn't quite think of `(values)` :D

Comment: Although in most contexts, returning the result of `(values)` is indistinguishable from returning `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

You did not really test it.

```
CL-USER 3 > (defun test ()
              (encrypt '(a))
              (encrypt '(a))
              (encrypt '(a))
              'lalala)
TEST

CL-USER 4 > (test)
HHH
LALALA

CL-USER 5 > (defun test1 ()
              (test)
              (test)
              (test)
              'mmmmmm)
TEST1

CL-USER 6 > (test1)
HHHHHHHHH
MMMMMM
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a REPL, so the value of each expression is Printed.

The value of `(encrypt x)` ends up (in this instance) being the value of `(princ 'H)` which is `H`.

*Additionally*, `(princ 'H)` prints `H`.

This is the same reason that you see `(A)` after evaluating `(setf x '(A))`